# Random sampling in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I performed random sampling from an array in Meteor (server side). Things like getting `n` samples with or without replacement from an array `const x = ['value2,'value2',value3', 'value4']` .. `Random.choice(.)` only gives one value back.

Comment: Just use `Random.choice()` inside a loop. If without replacement eliminate the selected item from the array each time.

Comment: Interesting that there isn't an already efficient implemented version of this in Random

Comment: You could contribute one! It's open-source.

Comment: There's an npm package available as well: [discrete-sampling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discrete-sampling)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `_.sample(arr, [n=1])` method ([documentation](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/1.5.2/index.html#sample))

Comment: Thanks! this works. But do you know why it is not recommended to use _. in Meteor anymore? and if so, is there an alternative.

Comment: Why do you think it's not recommended to use? The Meteor itself is using it.